# The transparency on my UV map doesnt apply

Tags: uv, transparency

So, I have this model i got from a website and i dont know why this doesn't work

[image]

These red and blue buttons shouldn't have that black background

[image]

And it only works when im in the texture paint window

[image]

All the imagess for the model that i have

[image]

[Here is the file, there are other models in the file, feel free to delete those](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dwBNUdGlL-9Hp-1heozdYjiRsL5BEwVz/view?usp=share_link)

[And here the images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uPV8bu5eRmbSJ-rcSb1ys_X9cA32basx?usp=share_link)

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot of your Shader Editor or even share your file?

Comment: @moonboots Done

Comment: You didn't pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) but I suspect you need to plug the Alpha output of the Image Texture into to Alpha input of the Principled BSDF?

Comment: @moonboots How do i do that? I added an image of all the uv maps

Comment: Pack the images  (File > External Data > Pack Resources), save and share again, if it's too heavy use another platform like workupload

Comment: @moonboots Done

Comment: See my edit, in Eevee you need to switch from Opaque to Alpha Blend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the alpha transparency to be taken acount you need to plug the *Alpha* output of the *Image Texture* into the *Alpha* input of the *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

Also, in Eevee you need to switch from *Blend Mode > Opaque* to *Alpha Blend*, disable *Show Backface*, and separate these faces as new object (<kbd>P</kbd>) otherwise you'll have a bug of transparency (as some *Alpha Blend* faces are seen through other *Alpha Blend* faces, which doesn't work fine in Eevee). Or as you say switch to *Alpha Hashed*:

[image]

[image]

That said, the method chosen here to put these circles over the coat may not be the best as the faces may overlap, why not simply remove these faces, use the faces behind instead, and paint a yellow background behind the circles instead of transparency?

Comment: It does something, but it only makes a little circle arround the buttons,and it doesn't take out all the black background

Comment: You still haven't shared the images, you need to remove all the useless objects, pack them, save the file, share again   ;)

Comment: Now it works, but i can see through the character :/ And i tried alpha clip and alpha hashed and it works xd

Comment: You also need to disable the Show Backface option but there's still a bug. Edit: Oh ok yes it's Alpha Blend through Alpha Blend, so you need to separate these faces as a new object...

Comment: What do you mean there's still a bug? -EDIT- Now the black things is there again xd, why not use the other alpha options instead of alph blend?

Comment: Yes you can use Alpha Hashed if the result suits you  ;)